# Proposition for software registration

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

When a user buy a software and enter a serial number, it is registered to the user? right?

If yes, what is the proposition for the *Register*

> This program is registered **with/to/for** XXX company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we generally say that **the product is registered to the user** who bought it.  If you're talking about the company that *sold* the software, it would be more normal to say that the program is registered **with** the company.  For example, ["Customers must have all Red Hat software registered with Red Hat to qualify for the warranty."](https://books.google.com/books?id=IwsAAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA97-IA3&ots=mjkduJiUtA&dq=%22software%20registered%20with%20Red%20Hat%22&pg=PA97-IA3#v=onepage&q=%22software%20registered%20with%20Red%20Hat%22&f=false)

By the way, [*software* is a **mass noun** or **uncountable noun**, so you can't say "a software"](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/is-software-a-mass-noun/).  Use "software" to speak of software in general, or "a program" if you need to talk about a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

There can also be the use of "by" to denote who handles the registration process.

> This program is registered by XXX company.